How to make a rectangle blink(in a specific frequency) animation in Winui3 in XAML?
I would love to make a rectangle blink(in a specific frequency) in my Winui3 project(in C++) in XAML, here is my code in XAML:
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Rear_Frame_Blink">
            <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="rec_rear" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="Automatic"  
                AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">                                
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    
    <Rectangle x:Name="rec_rear" Loaded="RearFrame_Start_blink" Width="2275" Height="480"  Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="12" Opacity="0.9"/>
    
</StackPanel>

And I want to make it start/stop blinking programmably in C++, with RearFrame_Start_blink function, with Rear_Frame_Blink.begin();
But it wouldn't work, with error like this: C++ identifier is undefined on Rear_Frame_Blink.
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks a lot!

Please share the C++ code since that is where you say the problem is. Also, there should be more xaml than just what you shared. What is the top level class that the StackPanel is inside?

Your code works for me just as the Theme animation example. Note, C# Rear_Frame_Blink.Begin(); C++ Rear_Frame_Blink().Begin();

Thanks, Yang, I used "Rear_Frame_Blink().Begin();" in my code, but I got  the following error, do you have any idea why? Thanks a lot! winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_IStoryboardwinrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Animation::IStoryboard::Begin': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined

Why does my C++/WinRT project get errors of the form “consume_Something: function that returns ‘auto’ cannot be used before it is defined”? You may share the C++ code as @RaymondChen said.

I finally solved this problem by adding "#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.h"" Thank you all the same!

Wait, you wrote this in the question "with error like this: C++ identifier is undefined on Rear_Frame_Blink", but in the comments you wrote a different error "function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined." It's hard to diagnose a problem when the wrong information is provided.

After I rebuild the project, the error "C++ identifier is undefined on Rear_Frame_Blink" disappeard. Don't know why, but it resolved itself. And after adding "#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.h", this problem is resolved"a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined" . That's all.

The code works for me just as the Theme animation example. But note It's different to refer to named resources. For example, in C# Rear_Frame_Blink.Begin();, in C++ Rear_Frame_Blink().Begin();.
As for errors of the form “consume_Something: function that returns ‘auto’ cannot be used before it is defined”?, please see @RaymondChen 's blog Why does my C++/WinRT project get errors of the form “consume_Something: function that returns ‘auto’ cannot be used before it is defined”?

For the impatient: The problem is that you are missing the header file
for the interface you are using.

